# How to Open HTML pages that uses Java Script in WebView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, webview, android-webview

I am able to load `WebPage` in my `WebView`. It also opens `Non-Javascript` links in `WebView`, but when it comes to `JavsScript` it does not do anything.

When i use this

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

It stop displaying anything in the `WebView`

I have written the following code. but JavaScript is not working in my `WebView`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_promotions);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv_promotions);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MavsWebViewClient());
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl(URL);
}


class MavsWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if(url.contains(URL)){
            view.loadUrl(URL); // Stay within this webview and load url
            return true;
        } else {
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url); 
        }
    }
}
```

I want all the activites to be happen in my `WebView`. Kindly guide me how to enable `JavaScript` in `WebView`